# Android TVs and LINUX 4.9.118+

Tags: linux, smart-tv

Perhaps an obvious question for some, but, is my Kogan brand Smart tv using Android and google play pre-installed apps running Linux 4.9.118+

Comment: Can you please check your posted text, I think you forgot to include the question. Please edit it and add your question. Stack Exchange is an Q&A system, therefore without a question we can't do anything here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing your doubt is about how an Android SmartTV have some info about Linux...

Surely you have saw this Linux info into Settings>About TV and this info is about the Linux Kernel version built-in the device.

BR